# Fitting a .wav file to target duration by speeding/slowing in python

Tags: python, audio, moviepy, librosa, pydub

I am currently trying to generate a TTS file of a subtitle file I generated. It's a basic loading and processing of the file where the timestamps' lines always start with a `##`. Code for cleaning subs:

```
duration = VideoFileClip(f"media/{name}.mp4").duration
for i in range(len(lines)):
    if '##' in lines[i]:
        timestamp = lines[i].replace('## ', '').replace(' :', '').replace(' :\n', '')
        start_time, end_time = map(float, timestamp.split(" - "))
        if lines[i + 1] == '\n':
            subtitle_entries.append({"start": start_time, "end": end_time,
                                     "text": "<empty>"})
    elif lines[i] == '\n':
        continue
    else:
        subtitle_entries.append({"start": start_time, "end": end_time,
                                 "text": lines[i].lstrip() if lines[i].lstrip() != '' else "<empty>"})
        data += lines[i][:-1] + ' '

final_entries = []
if subtitle_entries[0]['start'] != 0:
    final_entries.append({"start": 0, "end": subtitle_entries[0]['start'], "text": "<empty>"})

for i in range(len(subtitle_entries)):
    if i != 0 and subtitle_entries[i - 1]['end'] != subtitle_entries[i]['start']:
        final_entries.append({"start": subtitle_entries[i - 1]['end'], "end": subtitle_entries[i]['start'],
                              "text": "<empty>"})
    final_entries.append(subtitle_entries[i])

if subtitle_entries[-1]['end'] != total_dur:
    final_entries.append({"start": subtitle_entries[-1]['end'], "end": total_dur, "text": "<empty>"})
```

Just creates parts of objects to pass them to the TTS model. This is my logic of generating the final TTS audio:

```
from pydub import AudioSegment
for entry in final_entries:
    if entry['text'] == "<empty>":
        audio_files.append(AudioSegment.silent(duration=(entry['end'] - entry['start']) * 1000))
    else:
        tts.tts_to_file(text=entry['text'], file_path=f"media/{name}/{entry['end']}.wav")

        audio_file = AudioSegment.from_wav(f"media/{name}/{entry['end']}.wav")
        original_dur = len(audio_file)
        expected_dur = (entry['end'] - entry['start']) * 1000

        # Speedup or slow down the audio file here

        audio_files.append(audio_file)
```

The problem is, I have tried using librosa and pydub to speedup/slowdown the TTS file to match the given duration so that I can embed my audio to my targeted video file and it will sync up with what the speaker is speaking. I know I could have used commercial TTS APIs that do provide features of matching duration with TTS but I want to limit myself to Open-source APIs and so I would like to ask for help for writing a logic that essentially speeds up or slows down the audio by some factor (more like stretch or shrink) to match the given duration. How do I acheive that using libraries like librosa, pydub or moviepy?

I have tried using librosa, here are my error logs and code for the librosa implementation:

**Code**

```
for entry in final_entries:
    if entry['text'] == "<empty>":
        audio_files.append(AudioSegment.silent(duration=(entry['end'] - entry['start']) * 1000))
    else:
        tts.tts_to_file(text=entry['text'], file_path=f"media/{name}/{entry['end']}.wav")

        audio_file = AudioSegment.from_wav(f"media/{name}/{entry['end']}.wav")
        original_durr = len(audio_file)
        expected_durr = (entry['end'] - entry['start']) * 1000

        y, sr = librosa.load(f"media/{name}/{entry['end']}.wav")
        y_output = librosa.effects.time_stretch(y, rate=(expected_durr / original_durr))
        sf.write(f"media/{name}/{entry['end']}.wav", y_output, sr)

        audio_file = AudioSegment.from_wav(f"media/{name}/{entry['end']}.wav")
        audio_files.append(audio_file)
```

**Error logs**

```
Internal Server Error: /video_downloader/download/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\leofi\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 55, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\leofi\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 197, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Academics\transcriber\video_downloader\views.py", line 158, in download_video
    audio_file = tts_convertor(translated_file, target_language, name)
  File "C:\Academics\transcriber\video_processor\processor.py", line 148, in tts_convertor
    y_output = librosa.effects.time_stretch(y, rate=(expected_durr / original_durr))
  File "C:\Users\leofi\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\librosa\effects.py", line 245, in time_stretch
    stft_stretch = core.phase_vocoder(
  File "C:\Users\leofi\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\librosa\core\spectrum.py", line 1457, in phase_vocoder
    d_stretch[..., t] = util.phasor(phase_acc, mag=mag)
  File "C:\Users\leofi\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\librosa\util\utils.py", line 2602, in phasor
    z = _phasor_angles(angles)
  File "C:\Users\leofi\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\numba\np\ufunc\dufunc.py", line 190, in __call__
    return super().__call__(*args, **kws)
numpy.core._exceptions._UFuncNoLoopError: ufunc '_phasor_angles' did not contain a loop with signature matching types <class 'numpy.dtype[float32]'> -> None
ERROR:django.request:Internal Server Error: /video_downloader/download/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\leofi\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 55, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\leofi\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 197, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Academics\transcriber\video_downloader\views.py", line 158, in download_video
    audio_file = tts_convertor(translated_file, target_language, name)
  File "C:\Academics\transcriber\video_processor\processor.py", line 148, in tts_convertor
    y_output = librosa.effects.time_stretch(y, rate=(expected_durr / original_durr))
  File "C:\Users\leofi\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\librosa\effects.py", line 245, in time_stretch
    stft_stretch = core.phase_vocoder(
  File "C:\Users\leofi\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\librosa\core\spectrum.py", line 1457, in phase_vocoder
    d_stretch[..., t] = util.phasor(phase_acc, mag=mag)
  File "C:\Users\leofi\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\librosa\util\utils.py", line 2602, in phasor
    z = _phasor_angles(angles)
  File "C:\Users\leofi\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\numba\np\ufunc\dufunc.py", line 190, in __call__
    return super().__call__(*args, **kws)
numpy.core._exceptions._UFuncNoLoopError: ufunc '_phasor_angles' did not contain a loop with signature matching types <class 'numpy.dtype[float32]'> -> None
[03/Dec/2023 14:29:23] "POST /video_downloader/download/ HTTP/1.1" 500 141577
```

Comment: Did you try librosa's [time_stretch](https://librosa.org/doc/0.10.1/generated/librosa.effects.time_stretch.html#librosa.effects.time_stretch)? What was the problem?

Comment: I did, I was getting a DivisionByZero error, I debugged my application and found no attributes being passed that were set to 0.

Comment: There was also an error when I was trying to resave the modified file. This was my code in librosa:

y, sr = librosa.load(<file>)

y_output = librosa.effects.time_stretch(y, rate=expected_dur/original_dur)

sf.write(f"media/{name}/{entry['end']}.wav", y_output, sr)

audio_file = AudioSegment.from_wav(f"media/{name}/{entry['end']}.wav")

audio_files.append(audio_file)

Comment: (1) Show code and other textual information as properly formatted text in the question, not as comment, image or external link. (2) Show the full traceback of the error(s) as properly formatted text (formatted as code) in the question.

Comment: @MichaelButscher I added the logs and librosa implementation.